# r create a unique numeric value for every id in column

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

I have a dataset with a long list of random IDs like this.

```
 ID      
 H001  
 H00A  
 H00M  
 B00A  
 BB0B  
 AB0A  
 AA0B  
 AA0B  
 BB0B   
 H001  
 H00A  
 H001  
 H00M  
 H00Z  
 CC01  
 CD01  
 CC02  
 XT01  
 XT0A  
 XT0A
```

I like to create a new column with numeric values for each ID.  The final dataset would appear like this.

```
 ID      NumId
 H001    1
 H00A    2 
 H00M    3
 B00A    4
 BB0B    5
 AB0A    6
 AA0B    7
 AA0B    7
 BB0B    5
 H001    1
 H00A    2 
 H001    1 
 H00M    3
 H00Z    8
 CC01    9
 CD01    10
 CC02    11
 XT01    12
 XT0A    13
 XT0A    13
```

Any suggestions on how to create a numerically equivalent column is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the fact that factors are internally numeric this is quite easy:

```r
a<-c('a','b','c','a','b','e')
as.numeric(as.factor(a))
#> [1] 1 2 3 1 2 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your original ordering

```
tmp=df$ID[!duplicated(df$ID)]
match(df$ID,tmp)

 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  5  1  2  1  3  8  9 10 11 12 13 13
```